# Why was the Lord of the Rings/Solar System Question closed?

Tags: discussion

**[What would the Lord of the Rings' “solar system” look like?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/48446/what-would-the-lord-of-the-rings-solar-system-look-like)**

This question has now been, IMO, incorrectly closed.

The answer I supplied to it clearly demonstrates that it's **not** a "Primarily Opinion-Based" question as I took each of the 3 points in it (after the introductory preamble) and addressed them by citing sources and giving quotations:

- But is the realistic scientific view of our solar system a part of the Lord of the Rings universe?
- If I understand it correctly, though there has been a flat earth and a round earth...
- ...the Earth has always been the centre of the universe, with a much smaller sun and earth moving through the sky, like an actual geocentric model of the universe. Is this correct?

All of these have been asked and answered, and if a question can be answered in such a manner it surely cannot possibly be opinion-based.

Another possible reason may be "questions seeking scientific solutions or explanations are off-topic unless they relate directly to a cited work of fiction" -- but this question clearly does **relate directly to a cited work of fiction** (it's even cited in the question title).  That reason is therefore not valid either.

The close reason given is "This question does not appear to be about science fiction or fantasy within the scope defined in the help center" - but that indicates nothing and the question appears to have been closed in error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the title of the question probably contributed to the closure quite a bit.

I think the question is perfectly fine, and your answer is excellent.

However, "What would the Lord of the Rings' “solar system” look like?" looks like it is inviting speculation, and the comments given as explanation for some of the close votes indeed indicate that people felt the question was too speculative.

Clearly, it is answerable with some solid references, and I've voted to reopen.

I've also taken the liberty of editing the title a bit; hopefully that helps.